# How to use MVVM-Light with IMessenger to pass a value between 2 VMs in WIndows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8, mvvm-light, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have to click twice to be able to receive a message in my messenger what am I doing wrong? Am I not initiating the Messenger correctly I think ??

In my ViewModelLocator class:

```
 public class ViewModelLocator

    {
       static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPortabilityFactory, PortabilityFactory>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>((() => (IMessenger)new Messenger()));

            bla bla...
        }
bla bla...
```

In my Navigation class i have:

```
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        private IMessenger _messenger { get; set; }

        public NavigationService(IMessenger messenger)
        {
            _messenger = messenger;

        }
           bla bla...

public void NavigateToViewByChannelPage(Channel parameter)
            {
                //Sending info to ViewModel
                _messenger.Send(new IdParameter() { Id = parameter.Id }, typeof(ViewByChannelPageViewModel));

                //Going to page
                this.Navigate(typeof(ViewByChannelPage));
            }

bla bla...
```

and here is my first VM that calls the NavigationService and that navigates me to my page class:

```
 private void NavigateToChannel(Channel chan)
    {
        if (chan != null)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>().NavigateToViewByChannelPage(chan);
        }
    }
```

And here is my second VM that should receive the message page:

```
        public ViewByChannelPageViewModel(IMessenger messenger, IPortabilityFactory factory)
            : base(messenger)
        {
            _factory = factory;

            //Getting value passed
             messenger.Register<IdParameter>(this, typeof(ViewByChannelPageViewModel), message => UpdateContentPane(message.Id));

        }

        private async void UpdateContentPane(string videoId)
            {  
Bla bla....
    }
```

Basically I have to go twice to the same page for the messenger to work for the first time, then once I have done this the messenger will work perfectly.
It would seem that I have to initiate the messenger? has any one had this problem before?  As you can see I am new at using MVVM Light...
Thank for your help!
If you need more code ask away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from my navigation class, i needed to initialize my ViewByChannelPageViewModel before i could pass a value to it:

```
 public void NavigateToViewByChannelPage(Channel parameter)
        {
            //Must create an instance so that the page can recieve the info
Needed this -->  SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ViewByChannelPageViewModel>();

            //Sending info to ViewModel
            _messenger.Send(new IdParameter() {Id = parameter.Id});

            //Going to page
            this.Navigate(typeof(ViewByChannelPage));
        }
```

By the way: if you have a better way of navigating or improvements that I could make in this code I am all ears!
Thx